# How could dataframe(df) be put using specific function retrieving the correct dates, populating the new df with repeated information?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to add new rows of days, but repeat the information from the original data

```
startdate = c("2015-12-20", "2014-01-21", "2013-04-09")
endates = c("2015-12-25", "2014-01-31", "2013-04-13")
data = c(20, 30, 40)
df <- data.frame(startdate, endates, data)
```

I want this dataframe to look like this.

```
        dates         sd         ed newdata
1  2015-12-20 2015-12-20 2015-12-25      20
2  2015-12-21 2015-12-20 2015-12-25      20
3  2015-12-22 2015-12-20 2015-12-25      20
4  2015-12-23 2015-12-20 2015-12-25      20
5  2015-12-24 2015-12-20 2015-12-25      20
6  2015-12-25 2015-12-20 2015-12-25      20
7  2014-01-21 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
8  2014-01-22 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
9  2014-01-23 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
10 2014-01-24 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
11 2014-01-25 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
12 2014-01-26 2014-01-26 2014-01-31      30
13 2014-01-27 2014-01-26 2014-01-31      30
14 2014-01-28 2014-01-26 2014-01-31      30
15 2014-01-29 2014-01-26 2014-01-31      30
16 2014-01-30 2014-01-26 2014-01-31      30
17 2014-01-31 2014-01-26 2014-01-31      30
18 2013-04-09 2013-04-18 2013-04-13      40
19 2013-04-10 2013-04-18 2013-04-13      40
20 2013-04-11 2013-04-18 2013-04-13      40
21 2013-04-12 2013-04-18 2013-04-13      40
22 2013-04-13 2013-04-18 2013-04-13      40
```

I have started by constructing a function that expands the correct dates in between two dates through this function

```
timerange <- function(startvec, endvec) {
dates <- seq(as.Date(startvec), as.Date(endvec), by="days")
return(dates)
}
```

Now, how could I go about putting my df through this function, retrieving the correct dates, and populating the new dataframe with repeated information?

Comment: I think in the expected output `sd` for 18:22 should be `2013-04-09`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first need to convert the `factor` class of 'Date' columns to `Date` class.  Then, using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to `data.table` (`setDT(df)`), grouped by the sequence of rows (`1:nrow(df)`), we get the `seq` of 'startdate' to 'endates', and cbind with the other columns to get the expected output.

```
df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], as.Date)
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(df)[, list(dates=seq(startdate, endates, by = '1 day'),
        sd= startdate, ed=endates, newdata= data),
                     by = 1:nrow(df)][, nrow:= NULL][]

res
#         dates         sd         ed newdata
# 1: 2015-12-20 2015-12-20 2015-12-25      20
# 2: 2015-12-21 2015-12-20 2015-12-25      20
# 3: 2015-12-22 2015-12-20 2015-12-25      20
# 4: 2015-12-23 2015-12-20 2015-12-25      20
# 5: 2015-12-24 2015-12-20 2015-12-25      20
# 6: 2015-12-25 2015-12-20 2015-12-25      20
# 7: 2014-01-21 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
# 8: 2014-01-22 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
# 9: 2014-01-23 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
#10: 2014-01-24 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
#11: 2014-01-25 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
#12: 2014-01-26 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
#13: 2014-01-27 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
#14: 2014-01-28 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
#15: 2014-01-29 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
#16: 2014-01-30 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
#17: 2014-01-31 2014-01-21 2014-01-31      30
#18: 2013-04-09 2013-04-09 2013-04-13      40
#19: 2013-04-10 2013-04-09 2013-04-13      40
#20: 2013-04-11 2013-04-09 2013-04-13      40
#21: 2013-04-12 2013-04-09 2013-04-13      40
#22: 2013-04-13 2013-04-09 2013-04-13      40
```